# Show that M is a subspace from

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

M =  \begin{bmatrix}
        a & b \\
        c & 0 \\
     \end{bmatrix}

with $a + b - 2c = 0$

Show that M is a subspace from $M_{2:2} (\mathbb{R})$

[$M_{2:2} (\mathbb{R})$ is the ring of 2 \times 2 matrices over the real numbers]

can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

To show $M$ is a subspace, you need to show that $M$ is closed under addition and scalar multiplication.

Scalar Multiplication: 
$$k\begin{bmatrix}
        a & b \\
        c & 0 \\
     \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
        ka & kb \\
        kc & 0 \\
     \end{bmatrix}$$
Since we know $a + b - 2c = 0$, what can we say about $ka + kb - k2c$?

Addition: 
$$\begin{bmatrix}
        a & b \\
        c & 0 \\
     \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}
        d & e \\
        f & 0 \\
     \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
        a +d & b+e \\
        c+f & 0 \\
     \end{bmatrix}$$
This time we know that $a + b - 2c = 0$ and $d + e - 2f = 0$. So what can we say about $(a+d) + (b +e) - 2(c + f)$?

Comment: thanks for Deven Ware... your answer help me...